# Identify duplicates by comparing 2 or more columns from two different database

Tags: python, dataframe, data-mining, data-modeling

I have 2 read only databases db1 and db2. I want to compare rows between these databases and database itself to get the similar matching records.

Supplier Name & Number, Invoice Amount, Invoice Date, Invoice # would be the comparable. The more matches within  the same transaction the higher the chance of it being a duplicate.

Example 1: We have data from Table db1 and db2 and Expected Result would be as follows:

Table db1:

Supplier Name / Supplier # / Invoice #  /  Invoice Date /    Invoice Amount

```
Cintas   /    100001234  /  8001   /  5-17-2019  /  Rs.450.00 
Cintas   /    100001234  /  9001   /  6-17-2019  /  Rs.220.00  
ABB      /    10025552   /  25255  /  5-01-2019  /  Rs.550
Abc      /    100001122  /  154666 /  5-21-2019  /  Rs.180
```

Table db2:

Supplier Name / Supplier # / Invoice #  /  Invoice Date / Invoice Amount

```
Cintas /    100001234   /  8001    /  5-17-2019  /  Rs.450.00 
Cintas /    100001234   /  9001    /  6-17-2019  /  Rs.550.00
Bcc    /    102103312   /  154666  /  5-05-2019  /  Rs.180  
xyz    /    100001414   /  100012  /  5-21-2019  /  Rs.750.00
Acc    /    10210331f   /  154666  /  5-05-2019  /  Rs.180
```

Expected Result: First pair matched all columns, second pair matched all columns except Invoice Amount and Third pair matched only Invoice# and invoice Amount.

Supplier Name / Supplier # / Invoice #  /  Invoice Date / Invoice Amount

```
Cintas /    100001234   /   8001    /  5-17-2019  /   Rs.450.00  
Cintas /    100001234   /   8001    /  5-17-2019  /   Rs.450.00 

Cintas /    100001234   /   9001    /  6-17-2019  /   Rs.220.00 
Cintas /    100001234   /   9001    /  6-17-2019  /   Rs.550.00   

Abc    /    100001122   /   154666  /  5-21-2019  /   Rs.180 
Acc    /    10210331f   /   154666  /  5-05-2019  /   Rs.180
```

Example 2:  The below example would most likely be presented as a very high likelihood of being a duplicate.

```
Supplier Name / Supplier # / Invoice # /    Invoice Date /  Invoice Amount     
Cintas /    100001234   /     8001    /    5-17-2019  /   Rs.450.00  
Cintas /    100001234   /     8001    /    5-17-2019  /   Rs.450.00
```

Example 3:  This example would also be highlighted as a potential, but at a less likelihood as the matched criteria only presents Supplier, Invoice #,  Invoice Date.

Supplier Name /   Supplier # /   Invoice # /   Invoice Date /  Invoice Amount

```
Cintas /    100001234 /   9001   /   6-17-2019  /   Rs.220.00 
Cintas /    100001234 /   9001   /   6-17-2019  /   Rs.550.00
```

They rank the potential duplicate with a % for example 90/75/50/25%, the higher the percent the greater chance the tool feels it’s a duplicate.

Please suggest the algorithm or tool to find the duplicates from around 10,00,000 records and get % matches as per the columns matches.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This is just programming you have to do..  I don't think there's any real magic to it. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.  Why don't you get started writing some code to attempt to address your need.  Then, if you have problems, show us your code and where you're running into trouble.  Ask us questions about your code instead of asking for a canned solution.  (btw, what is "itself"?)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. "itself" means compare rows with same database.